# Passing GKSession to new CCLayer objects?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

So I'm adding some local bluetooth networking with GameKit, and here's some problems I'm imagining, hopefully you can tell me why they're imaginary:

My GKPickerController gets launched by my Menu, a CCLayer object that's been pushed to the CCSharedDirector.  Once the GKPickerController establishes a connection, it passes a GKSession to my menu layer.

So now the whole session belongs to my menu, but I want to put the data into other CCLayer objects (like the game itself!).  How do I make the GKSession global?  Can I simply add a method and just pass the whole Session to the new CCLayer subclass?  Will that preserve the whole session?

Thanks a ton in advance, I'm having a blast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a class with a sharedInstance method and have that class do all the global stuff?

Something like:

```
@interface GameController : NSObject {
   GKSession *gamekit_session;
}

+ (GameController *)sharedInstance;

- (void)initGameKitSession:(NSDictionary *)config;

- (GKSession *)getGameKitSession;

- (BOOL)isMyKittenAlive;

- (void)shutdownTheInternet:(BOOL)orly;

- (float)getGlobalWarmingTemperature;

- (void)doSomeOtherGlobalStuff;

@end
```

That way all your CCLayers can gain access to the GKSession by calling `[[GameController sharedInstance] getGameKitSession];`. It's safer and more elegant to use this technique rather than passing the `GKSession` around (I can't imagine the retain/release hell that you are going to step into ....)

Comment: I was actually really wondering about this...  I guess I just don't completely understand class methods.  I was under the impression that if you called sharedInstace (in your case), you would get some constant response, defined only by the class.  What you're telling me is that it will pass me whatever is allocated in the original GameController instance?  What if there were multiple instances of GameController?  How would the compiler know how to respond to my [[GameController sharedInstance] getGameKitSession] call then?

Comment: @DanF you just have to implement sharedInstance method to only create the instance once and store it in a static variable. When called the second time you can just return the static variable. And since you are the one using it, you should discipline yourself to always use the sharedInstance method and not the alloc/init method. Look at how CCDirector implemented the sharedDirector method. It's the same concept.

Comment: So that's what static means!  And refering to sharedDirector makes perfect sense.  As a very new coder, I'm still gaining the confidence to dig through and reverse-engineer methods I don't understand.  I really appreciate the guidance, a lack of global variables have really held me back.